# Removing user from viewing a folder who has access from another Group

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, office-365, groups

In Office 365 SharePoint online, my users are in custom Groups with specific Read/Write Access to different Document Libraries.

User John has Read-access to a folder called "Clients" inside a Documents Library called "BUSIT" because he belongs to a Group called "Project Manager".  There are other members in this Group as well.

Now, I want to set additional permissions so that John does not have **any access** to a specific folder (called "YouHaveNoAccess") inside this "Clients" folder. I have used "Stop Inheriting Permissions" on the folder "YouHaveNoAccess" but unsure what to do next or if I am even on the right path. Need to figure out how to exclude him from this one folder, even though he has access to all the other folders inside "Clients".

(We do not user PowerShell.)

Comment: If "Project Manager" group has access to "YouHaveNoAccess" folder, you cannot exclude him from this folder. You will have to remove "Project Manager" group access from this folder only then he will not be able to access the folder. You may need to create separate group to grant access to restricted folders. Let me know if it clarifies your doubt or you still need help with this.

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MicrosoftMVP Thanks. So, really there is no way to restrict his access from this one folder if he belongs to the Group that has access to it, correct..??  Even if I create a second group for him with no access to the restricted folder, he will still be able to access it as he would still belong to the first Group, correct...??

Comment: @Saira I understand that.  My question was can John be BOTH in the original group where he has access and then also in a new Group, where he does NOT have access to that one folder, and this second Group takes precedence over the first Group and he is denied access to that one folder....??

Comment: @Saira Ok.  How would I remove direct access for only him for that one folder is the million-dollar question. Can you please expand..??

Comment: You have to create another group where John will not be a member of the group, Assign permissions to this new group on restricted folder and remove old group from restricted folder permissions.

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MicrosoftMVP Sorry, I am a little confused.  So put John in BOTH groups, the old one where he HAS access and a new Group, where he does NOT have access...??  The old Group will continue to have other members as it is setup currently and the new Group will have ONLY John as a member.  And then if I apply both Groups to John, then he will continue to have access to all folders in "Clients" EXCEPT that one folder called "YouHaveNoAccess"...??

Comment: @user3512522, John should be member of only one group, "Project Manager". Check more details in my answer below for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "Project Manager" group has access to "YouHaveNoAccess" folder, you cannot exclude particular group member (John) from this folder.

You will have to remove "Project Manager" group access from this folder. Then only John will not be able to access the folder. You will have to create separate group to grant access to restricted folders.

Follow below steps:

1. Create one more SharePoint group (say you named it as a "Restricted Group")
2. Add all members/users from "Project Manager" group to the new "Restricted Group" **except** John. *John should not be the member of the new "Restricted Group"*
3. Go to permissions settings of "YouHaveNoAccess" folder and "Stop Inheriting Permissions" for "YouHaveNoAccess" folder
4. **Remove** "Project Manager" group from "YouHaveNoAccess" folder permissions
5. **Add** "Restricted Group" group to "YouHaveNoAccess" folder permissions

This way, all users will have access to "YouHaveNoAccess" folder **except** John.